# What should be the format of the '.node-version' file, and where should I place it?

Tags: node.js

This file instructs NodeJS version managers (such as [avn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avn) and [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv), and I guess that there are more) - which node version to use.

However, I have not been able to find anywhere, which format this file should abide to.

For example, should it be a JSON file? And if yes, what keys and values should it contain?

Running `node --version` gives me `v8.11.2`.

Also, where exactly should I place this file? My hunch tells me that it should reside next the `package.json` file in each one of my repositories, is that correct?

Comment: From the `avn` readme file : `What goes in your .node-version file? A semver version number corresponding to the version of Node.js that your project uses.` Have you tried just putting "`v8.11.2`" in the file ?

Comment: @Seblor: Yes, I noticed that line, however, it doesn't quite tell me what `semver ersion number` mean. I can use `v8.11.2` of course, I just want to be sure about this.

Comment: `semver` is short for [`Semantic Versioning`](https://semver.org/). This is how any npm module version is written, as npm uses the semver notation to manage the versions.

Comment: @Seblor: Yes, I read that one as well (the previous documentation line links to it). Wasn't sure in several things, for example, whether or not I should add `v`. I get your point. So where should I place it? Next to `package.json`?

Comment: I guess the project root folder should be the right place to put the file. I do not think you need to add the `v` because the readme states (in the io.js section) : `Plugins support a consistent syntax in the .node-version file for specifying the use of io.js rather than node. Simply add an iojs prefix. For instance: iojs-1.4 or iojs-v1.4.` So if you remove the prefix, you get `8.11.2` or `v8.11.2`. But I usually add it to identify a semver when I can

Comment: @Seblor: Thank you!!!

Answer (score 12):

The `.node-version` file is read by multiple projects, but there is not a defined standard.

In my testing, the format that worked with every product is a three part version number on a single line with a unix line ending.

e.g.

```
8.11.2
```

I documented usage and some supported features here: https://github.com/shadowspawn/node-version-usage